# fetching wordpress live data into my local local laravel api

Tags: wordpress, laravel, corcel

Im using corcel in my laravel local api, I can fetch wordpress data on my local wordpress site. When I try to change the settings to connect to a live wordpress site its not working. My question is, Is it possible? or do I need to make it both live in the same server since the wordpress site it on the shared hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You have to put on a public server both wordpress and laravel, and connect them.

Comment: do they need to be in the same server?

Comment: It will be better and easier if they are in the same server, yes.